# creating a Jar from java - command passes without any file created

Tags: java, jar

I am compiling a .jar as a library for Processing, following this guide.
However, my terminal passes the jar cvf without creating any file.

So my file structure is that:

`main > com > example > Example.class    (and Example.java)`

sitting in main, I give this command in my terminal:

```
`jar cvf /tmp/example.jar com/`
```

getting following:

```
`added manifest
adding: com/(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)
adding: com/.DS_Store(in = 6148) (out= 412)(deflated 93%)
adding: com/example/(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)
adding: com/example/Example.class(in = 864) (out= 600)(deflated 30%)
adding: com/example/Example.java(in = 710) (out= 332)(deflated 53%)`
```

but no file created. I tried to specify class by passing this command instead:

```
`sudo jar cvf /example.jar com/example/Example.class`
```

but this did not help either.

Comment: check in the current directory where you are opening terminal & giving commands using `pwd` & see the file there if present or not

Comment: Can you try searching for files ending in `.jar`?  This sounds stupid, but maybe the JAR file _was_ created but in a location you did not expect.

Comment: Have you looked in `/tmp`?

Comment: Where have you looked for the jar file? Why do you use /tmp/example.jar the first time, and /example.jar the second time? Do you realize that `/` represents the root of the file system, and not the current directory?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't reproduce your problem

```
$ ~/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/jar cvf /tmp/example.jar so
```

executes successfully on Debian where `so` is relative path to current directory where terminal is open. For existence of output I checked using:

```
$ ls -l /tmp/example.jar 
-rw-r--r-- 1 popeye popeye 24759 Jul 19 12:47 /tmp/example.jar
```

Did you look for jar file in `/tmp` directory?

Comment: the thing is It did not want to produce this tmp folder, but jar was created when I replaced "/tmp/example.jar" with "example.jar"

Comment: @Casy_fill `example.jar` is relative path, it was created in both cases but output was in different directory